# Powershell accessing browser tabs

Tags: browser, powershell-2.0

We are using PowerShell to automate testing of our website.

The process is as follows:
We open a tab containing a report and then we click on the print button which opens a new tab which contains a printer friendly version of our report but then when we try to print the printer friendly page it still has focus on the originating page and not the newly created page. How would we get a handle on the new page so we can print it and then close it.

Any help would really be appreciated

Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just ensure the browser is set to activate the new tab when it is created.  In Firefox, this is done via Tools > Options > Tabs > "When I open a link in a new tab, switch to it immediately".
I'm sure there must be a similar setting in IE.